# Not getting correct Store ID

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I have magento 1.9.2.x set up with 2 websites, each with their own store view.

Website 2's `local.xml` file:

```
<cms_page>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="page/html" name="abc" template="page/html/abc.phtml" />
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

Website 2's `1column.phtml` page:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('abc') ?>
```

Website 2's `/page/html/abc.phtml` file:

```
$store_id = 'unfound';
$website_id = 'unfound';

if (strlen($code = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getStore())) { // store level
    $store_id = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($code)->getId();
} elseif (strlen($code = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getWebsite())) { // website level
    $website_id = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($code)->getId();
    $store_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite($website_id)->getDefaultStore()->getId();
} else { // default level
    $store_id = 0;
}

echo '<pre>store id: ' . $store_id . ' | website id: ' . $website_id . ' </pre>';
```

When I navigate to Website 2, I see everything I expect, the website is displaying correctly, using the correct Store View.

However the code in `/page/html/abc.phtml` produces the following output:

```
store id: 0 | website id: unfound
```

Can anyone tell me why this isnt picking up the correct website id, and how to fix it? Please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Above code is for admin. to get this value in frondend you can use `Mage::app();`

```
    <?php 

//To Get the current store $store = Mage::app()->getStore(); //To get Store Id 
  $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(); //To get Store Code              
  $store_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode(); //To get Website Id 

$store_website_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId(); //To get Store Name 

$store_name = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); //To get Store Status 

$store_status = Mage::app()->getStore()->getIsActive(); //To get Store Home Url 
$store_home_url = Mage::app()->getStore()->getHomeUrl();
```

may be work for you.